# flickr api search not displaying images

Tags: jquery, ajax, each, getjson, flickr

When I click the search button and view the net tab in firebug it shows that the JSON objects are being returned, but I cannot get them to load into my browser to view. If I piece together the parts of "var url" into the address bar it also works.  I think the error might have something to do with the last function but I cannot figure it out.

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">     
  <style>
  img {
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
  }
  #images{
    width: 100%;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>   
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="flickrInput">
    <button id="flickrSearch">Search Photos</button>
    <div id="images"></div>      
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#flickrSearch").click(function (event) {
      var searchVal = $("#flickrInput").val();
      var flickrAPI = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=dd4a16666bdf3c2180b43bec8dd1534a";
      $.getJSON( flickrAPI, {
        tags: searchVal,
        per_page: 25,
        format: "json"
      },  
        function( data ) {
        $.each( data.items, function( i, item ) {
          var url = 'https://farm' + item.farm + '.staticflickr.com/' + item.server + '/' + item.id + '_' + item.secret + '.jpg';
         $('#images').append('<img src="' + url + '"/>');
       });
     });
  });    
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Code is working and performing a request. But Flicks answer is not a valid JSON: `"jsonFlickrApi({"photos":{"page":1,"pages":12207,"perpage":25,"total":"305156","photo":[{"id":"19639656861","owner":"30271324@N07","secret":"0280357dc4","server":"260","farm":1,"title":"193_12.07.2015_Sommer","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0}/*, ...*/]},"stat":"ok"})"`. It seems that API has been changed and example became invalid.

Comment: ok I changed var flickrAPI to   `var flickrAPI = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=dd4a16666bdf3c2180b43bec8dd1534a&nojsoncallback=1";` to remove the function wrapper...  still not working tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Flickr API has been changed and your example is outdated.

You just need to investigate what data is coming from API using Google Chrome developer console or using breakpoints and watches.

[image]

[image]

There is a working snippet:

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#flickrSearch").click(function (event) {
      var searchVal = $("#flickrInput").val();
      var flickrAPI = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=dd4a16666bdf3c2180b43bec8dd1534a&nojsoncallback=1";
      $.getJSON( flickrAPI, {
        tags: searchVal,
        per_page: 25,
        format: "json"
      },  
        function( data ) {
        $.each( data.photos.photo, function( i, item ) {
          var url = 'https://farm' + item.farm + '.staticflickr.com/' + item.server + '/' + item.id + '_' + item.secret + '.jpg';
         $('#images').append('<img src="' + url + '"/>');
       });
     });
  });    
});
```

```css
  img {
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
  }
  #images{
    width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input type="text" id="flickrInput">
    <button id="flickrSearch">Search Photos</button>
    <div id="images"></div>
```

Comment: It works great and thank you for your detailed response. You wouldn't believe me but I figured it out moments before and was coming back on here to post about it, but your response looks way better than anything I would have done.  Thanks again/